# Sending data from three different text view in main activity to one text view in another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three text view and three button associated to text views in main activity and one text view in second activity. I want to transfer data to text view when any of the button clicked.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreference` or `Bundle` for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Intent extras to pass data between activities.

**Activity1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("data1" , "data_value_1");
intent.putExtra("data2" , "data_value_2");
startActivity(intnent);
```

**Activity2**

In onCreate()

```
String data1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("data1");
String data2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("data2");
```

And set the data to your textview.